# How can I turn off output cache via web.config in asp.net mvc 4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, web-config

How can I turn off output cache via web.debug.config in asp.net mvc 4 app?
I try to do it:

web.debug.config

```
  <caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
  </caching>
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 19):

The `web.config.debug` file is used only when you build a [deployment package](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx) . If you run your site locally in Cassini for example it is completely ignored. So you may try disabling cache in your `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
        <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
    </caching>
</system.web>
```